# Pyqt: passing a name form login dialog to MainWindow

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

Here is my code.all is working fine.but I want to display a name (entered in login dialog) in a label in MainWindow .

```
 import sys
 from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
 from loginD import *
 from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
 class Login(QtGui.QDialog):

  def __init__(self,parent=None):
    QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self,parent)
    self.ui=Ui_LoginD()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.ui.PasswordLE.setEchoMode(QtGui.QLineEdit.Password)
    pilot=str(self.ui.PilotNameLE.text())
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.LoginPB,QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),
                           self.HandleLogin)
 def HandleLogin(self):
    if  self.ui.PasswordLE.text()=="a":
        self.accept()
    else:
        QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(
            self,'Error;','bad')
class Main_Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self, parent=None):
     QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
     self.ui=Ui_MainWindow()
     self.ui.setupUi(self)
     self.ui.PioltNameL.setText(str(pilot) )
if __name__=='__main__':
  app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  if Login().exec_()==QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
    window=Main_Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want to pass pilot ( from pilotnamelinediet ) in dialog class to pilotname label in MainWindow class.how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post working example (keep in mind that we don't have your `loginD` and `Ui_MainWindow`), 
anyway, this should work:

**1)** in `Login` class fix this `pilot=str(self.ui.PilotNameLE.text())` to `self.pilot=str(self.ui.PilotNameLE.text())`  and add method:

```
def GetPilot(self):
    return self.pilot
```

**2)** in `Main_Window` class change `__init__` line to:

```
def __init__(self, pilot, parent=None):
```

**3)** and this is how main should look like:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    loginDialog = Login()
    if loginDialog.exec_()==QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
        window=Main_Window(loginDialog.GetPilot())# pass pilot from login to mainwindow
        window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I did not test it so correct me if there are any mistakes

**EDIT** Once you have `self.pilot` string in `Main_Window` you can set it to `pilotname` label like this:

```
self.ui.pilotname.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", self.pilot, None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

or try simply with: `self.ui.pilotname.setText(self.pilot)`

If "pilotname" is name of label in your ui file.

Comment: Thanks,but how do I assign pilot name to label in mainwindow?

Comment: sorry, I've missed that. Take a look at **EDIT** in my answer

Comment: I think you've misspelled label name in this line: `self.ui.PioltNameL.setText(str(pilot) )`